# Using Pandas Styler

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

This may be a very dumb question, but I cannot seem to see the output of the Pandas Styler.  I use the following simple example posted previously by another user.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[3,2,10,4],[20,1,3,2],[5,4,6,1]])
df.style.background_gradient()
```

I understand the output of df.style creates a Styler object but how can I actually visualize this?

Comment: You must be using a jupyter notebook which automatically renders the Styler objects. Else, you need to specifically call the `render()` function, like `df.style.background_gradient().render()` and do file open/write/close and go to that html file and view the rendering. It's a rather cumbersome process. So, try and use ipython notebooks for such purposes.

Comment: added following and it works:  f = open(path+filename,'w'); f.write(df.style.background_gradient().render()); f.close().... Thanks so much

Comment: @racket99 I am having a similar problem and couldnt figure out a way to print in pycharm using styler. I wasnt able to figure out using files option that you shared. Would you be able to share a snippet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dataframe styling will only be rendered in [Jupyter notebooks](http://jupyter.org/). Your code, for instance, looks like this:

[image: Rendered dataframe in a notebook]

You can experiment with notebooks on [tmpnb.org](http://tmpnb.org) if you don't have it installed.