# How to mark strings in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

I have a Pandas Dataframe where each column is Series of strings. The strings represent the path to files that might be or not be physically present on the hard drive. 
I would like to mark the path pointing to not existent files, i.e. by coloring the string or its background.

Unfortunately I can't use [Styler.applymap(func)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.applymap.html#pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.applymap) because func should take a scalar input, not a string.

Also I just got that anyway Styler wouldn't really work for me because I use the Pycharm python console or the terminal on Ubuntu, [not Jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40268630/using-pandas-styler)

What can I do?

---

Example function for checking the existence of a file and returning a color

```
def color_not_existent_file(path):
    color = ('red' if not os.path.exists(path) else 'green')
    return 'color: {}'.format(color)
```

Comment: what's your end goal? why does it need to be colored vs. adding a flag field to the dataframe?

Comment: I don't "need" colors. I need a way to easily check if some files are missing or not.
A flag was my first thought, but then I should add one additional column for every existent column in the DataFrame, basically doubling the number of columns. I would prefer not to add so much overhead, hence the idea of coloring.